# internet explorer 8 and margins

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have some pretty simple html
which is meant to make a layout as below.

To push the tabs down from the userbar I am using
`margin-top: 35px;`
However in internet explorer the tabs are completly misaligned(the top of the tabs is where the bottom should be).

So I need to use `margin-top: -50px;` for internet explorer.

Why is this and how can I fix it without using a ie specific stylesheet

[layout example http://webspirited.com/layout.png](http://webspirited.com/layout.png)

```
<div id="pageHead">
  <div id="userBar">
    <span class="bold">Hi Matthew Hailwood | <a href="#">Logout</a>
  </div>
  <a href="http://localhost/buzz/" id="pageLogo"></a>  
  <div id="pageTabs" class="clearfix">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://localhost/buzzil/templates">Templates</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://localhost/buzzil/messaging">Messaging</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://localhost/buzzil/contacts">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the css being

```
#pageHead {
    height: 100px;
}

#pageLogo {
    float: left;
    width: 149px;
    height: 77px;
    margin-top: 11px;
    background: transparent url('../images/logo.png') no-repeat;
}

#userBar {
    text-align: right;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#userBar a:link,
#userBar a:visited,
#userBar a:active {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #E0B343;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}

#pageTabs {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 35px;
}

#pageTabs ul {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

#pageTabs ul li {
    float: right;
    background: url(../images/tabsBg.png) no-repeat 0% 0%;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    margin-left: -1px;
}

#pageTabs ul li a:link,
#pageTabs ul li a:visited,
#pageTabs ul li a:active {
    color: #fff;
    background: url(../images/tabsBg.png) no-repeat 100% 0%;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 42px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 4px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#pageTabs ul li a:hover,
#pageTabs ul li a:focus {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE does not like negative margins, it tends to have discrepancies. Try using `position` instead, along with `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` - it's more compatible, from personal experience.

You may just be able to convert your whole page from margins to positioning with minor tweaks.

Comment: I am not using negative margins by default, using the negative margin fixes top issue, however that requires an ie only stylesheet.

Comment: however your comment on positioning worked, adding `position:relative` to the pageHead, and changing the pageTabs styles to `position:absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;` works

Answer (score 0):

Try not using the html tag for any kind of styling. Use the body tag instead.
Also, try setting your pageHead to relative positioning, and then position the other divs via relative or absolute and using top, bottom, left, right, as MT mentioned.

xD Looks like I was a bit late. Sorry. :3

Comment: those styles are the universal clearfix 8D look it up, saves  A LOT of headaches!